# java: поиск в txt и print найденной строки и следующей

Tags: java

Моя программа ищет значение в файле и печатает всю строку в которой есть это значение! как заставить печатать и следующую строку после найденной?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String filePath = "C:\\file.txt";
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));



    String wanted1 = "1234";

for(String ln:lines)
        if(ln.contains(wanted1))
            // ln.indexOf(1, length)
    System.out.println("строка_1      "+ln);
    System.out.println()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (ln.contains(wanted1)) {
    // ln.indexOf(1, length)
    System.out.println("строка_1      " + ln);

    if (lines.indexOf(ln) == lines.size() - 1) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("строка_2      " + lines.get(lines.indexOf(ln) + 1));
}
```

Comment: работает) спасибо огромное!

Comment: наверняка обвалится, если найденная строка сама последняя.

Comment: там файл больше 100 000 строк а будет ещё больше))

Comment: да и можно пустую строку в конец файла добавить))

Comment: @Эникейщик вы правы, перепишу.

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov пустая строка не будет прочитана, только если в ней нет спецсимволов.

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov обновил, посмотрите.

Comment: круто! теперь прога проверяет есть следующая строка если есть печатать! спасибо!